# How to prove a Distributive lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Do we need to apply distributive law for all elements to prove distributive lattice?
Since every chain is distributive so don't need to apply for chains(right?) & also the two distributive laws are equivalent, so don't need to apply both(right?), but for larger lattices having many elements (excluding chains), there are also many elements to apply the distributive law & we have to do lengthy work.
Is there any other way to prove a distributive lattice?
I tried to find myself, but found nothing.

Comment: I don't understand your questions. Can you add the context for your questions?

Comment: I want to ask that ,can we prove a lattice to be distributive without checking distributive law?